# How to remove this error?fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

```
<ipython-input-9-118d9cffeb5d> in <module>()
      1 # Predict using BaggingClassifier on the test data
----> 2 bagging.fit(testing_data)
      3 
      4 # Predict using RandomForestClassifier on the test data
      5 clf.fit(testing_data)

TypeError: fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'
```

I am getting this error while modeling.

Comment: you missed the `target_vector`  `y` in `fit`

Comment: I was trying to predict the things instead I should have used bagging.predict

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation:

> Build a Bagging ensemble of estimators from the training set (X, y).
>
> X : {array-like, sparse matrix} of shape = [n_samples, n_features] The
> training input samples. Sparse matrices are accepted only if they are
> supported by the base estimator.
>
> y : array-like, shape = [n_samples] The target values (class labels in
> classification, real numbers in regression).

You need have one more parameter in the method. Something like:

```
model.fit(X_test, Y_test)
```

This will be helpful for understanding the parameters better: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html

Hope this helps. Good luck.